# In Cocoa, how is the id type defined?

Tags: cocoa

This question is out of pure curiosity. How does Cocoa define the id type? Is it just a typedef for a void *? Also, if you know which header file it is defined in, I would be interested in taking a look.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hold down the command key and double click on any highlighted term to jump to its definition.

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;


typedef struct objc_selector    *SEL;    
typedef id          (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...);
```

Comment: +1 Great answer. I hope to work more with XCode in the next year, and the keyboard shortcut will be super helpful to know.

Comment: +1 over even my own answer. I already knew this, but it is just too damn useful.

Comment: opt-double-click will bring up the documentation, if any is available, too!

Comment: Hot keys to jump to definition cmd+ctrl+j.

Answer (score 8):

It is delcared in `/usr/include/objc/objc.h` (on Leopard) as follows:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

Which means it is not `void *` at all, but rather a pointer to a struct that contains a single member, pointing at the class definition. Interesting indeed.

I remember when I was just getting into C and learning that Objective-C was initially implemented as just a preprocessor layer on top of C. It isn't quite like that anymore.

The best reading on the topic I've found:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Answer (score 7):

in objc.h

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

To find out on your own, in XCode, right click *id* -- or any other type -- and select *Jump to definition*. It's interesting to note the similarities to other C/C++ based object systems; an object pointer -- an id -- points to a struct that starts with a point to shared class information. I many C++ implementations, that would be the virtual function table, as it would be with Microsoft's COM. In Cocoa, the particulars of objc_class aren't revealed to us in the header file.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` type is generally declared like:

```
typedef struct objc_object *id;
```

This is *critical* for Objective-C++ where the type is part of a mangled function name.

You can take a look in /usr/include/objc/objc.h

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the doc here : http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/runtime/objc.h 
Hope this will do a favor for you