# iOS > "id" vs. NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

Is there a difference between relating to an `Object` in a 'Polymorphic' way with the type `id` than as `NSObject *`?

In what way is:

```
NSString* aString = @"Hello";
id anObj = aString;
```

different than:

```
NSString* aString = @"Hello";
NSObject* anObj = aString;
```

Comment: It's the lines after that make the difference. What are you going to do with `anObj`?

Comment: I asked the same question before, feel free to refer to some of the answers there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903954/why-use-id-when-we-can-just-use-nsobject

Comment: This question is a duplicate of @TheAmateurProgrammer's

Comment: Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466777/whats-the-difference-between-declaring-a-variable-id-and-nsobject

Answer (score 13):

`id` is a special keyword used in Objective-C to mean “some kind of object.”  It does not contain `isa` pointer(`isa`, gives the object access to its class and, through the class, to all the classes it inherits from), So you lose compile-time information about the object.

```
NSString* aString = @"Hello";
id anObj = aString;
```

[image]

`NSObject` contain `isa` pointer.

```
NSString* aString = @"Hello";
NSObject* anObj = aString;
```

[image]

From [Objective-C Is a Dynamic Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW18)

Consider the following code:

```
id someObject = @"Hello, World!";
[someObject removeAllObjects];
```

In this case, someObject will point to an `NSString` instance, but the compiler knows nothing about that instance beyond the fact that it’s some kind of object. The `removeAllObjects` message is defined by some Cocoa or Cocoa Touch objects (such as `NSMutableArray`) so the compiler doesn’t complain, even though this code would generate an exception at runtime because an NSString object can’t respond to `removeAllObjects`.

Rewriting the code to use a static type:

```
NSString *someObject = @"Hello, World!";
[someObject removeAllObjects];
```

means that the compiler will now generate an error because `removeAllObjects` is not declared in any public `NSString` interface that it knows about.

Answer (score 7):

`id` is generic. By using `id` you're telling the compiler that you will fill in details about usage later. The compiler assumes that any code you have is correct and doesn't warn you about anything. At runtime checks are made to verify what you're trying to do and you will get an exception if your code is wrong.

`NSObject` is specific. By using `NSObject` you're telling the compiler exactly what the object is. When you try to call methods on it they will be checked against what `NSObject` understands. You will get compile time errors if you make a mistake.

All that said, you can just cast in both cases to get to another Class type.

Your concern is what you're going to do with the reference in the future. Generally, using `NSObject` doesn't have any benefits.

Comment: I would avoid using the word 'generic' when talking about `id`, because generic means something quite different than 'late bound object' in several other languages (like [c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) and [java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)). Someone coming from one of those languages could get confused easily and expect the same type of behavior out of `id`

Comment: @RyanR Good point. 'Anonymous' may be better suited.

Answer (score 2):

1. **id** is a language keyword but the **NSObject** is the base class in objective c.
2. For id, you dont need to typecast the object. But
       for NSObject, you have to typecast it into NSObject.
3. An id object
       can be used to invoke any methods. But NSObject object can be use to
       invoke only particular methods that are defined in NSObject

Answer (score 0):

When  using id, you can send it any known message and when using NSObject *, you can only send it messages declared by NSObject (not methods of any subclass) or else it will generate a warning.